# Reference external option values or functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my code an onclick event of a link selects a drop-down option:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on("click", "#aaa", function(){
              $("select").val("aaa").change();
            });
          });
        </script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on("click", "#bbb", function(){
              $("select").val("bbb").change();
            });
          });
        </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on("click", "#ccc", function(){
              $("select").val("ccc").change();
            });
          });
        </script>
  
</head>
<body>

<p><a id="aaa">Select Option 1</a></p>
<p><a id="bbb">Select Option 2</a></p>
<p><a id="ccc">Select Option 3</a></p>


<select>
        <option>Select</option>
            <option value="aaa">Option 1</option>
            <option value="bbb">Option 2</option>
            <option value="ccc">Option 3</option>
        </select>
</body>
</html>
```

**Issue:**

I am trying to add a link to an external page that navigates to the page with the above code and automatically selects e.g. Option 2

In a sense I am trying to execute e.g. the following function

```js
function() $("select").val("bbb").change();});
```

when clicking on a  particular (external) link that navigates to the page of the function first.

Comment: What do you mean by "external" link?

Comment: So you want to navigate to the other page and (on the other page) have option 2 selected?

Comment: Let's say the code above is "page_1". "page_2" contains <a href="/page_1/">. By clicking on <a> of "page_2" I would like to navigate to "page_1" and execute a function

Comment: @Scott Marcus: That is correct

Comment: You cant execute a function of your old page if your loading a New HTML file. You need to request the HTML with an Ajax call and load it dynamic in your current HTML site ( single page application)

Comment: @ Martin Godzina I am just trying to link to new page and execute a certain function on that new page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to send some sort of parameter to the second page that that page can read. The simplest thing would be to add a query string onto the link, like this:

```
<a href="http://www.someDomain.com/page2.html?option=2">Page 2</a>
```

And then on "page2.html", you'll need to read the query string and act accordingly:

```js
// This is the code that would be on page2.html
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  // Assume that the current page was arrived at with the URL: http://someDomain.com/page2.html?option=2
  // That is the string that will be in window.location.href
  //var theQueryString = window.location.href;

  // For testing purposes we'll use it as a variable:
  var theQueryString = "http://someDomain.com/page2.html?option=2".split("?")[1]; 
  var optionNumber = theQueryString.split("=")[1];
  console.log(theQueryString, optionNumber);
  
  if(optionNumber === "2"){
    // You can do whatever you need to do now that you know what the parameter 
    // was that was passed from the first page:
    document.getElementById("foo").selectedIndex = optionNumber - 1; 
    
    doSomethingAwesome();
  }

  function doSomethingAwesome(){ alert("You Did It!"); }

});
```

```html
<select id="foo">
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
  <option>Four</option>      
</select>
```

Comment: The selection works beautifully, the issue I am still having is that the event associated with a selection isn't being triggered.

Comment: @FatTwin As you can see in my example, the `doSomethingAwesome()` function is being called as it should. If that's not happening for you, you have another, separate issue. Check your console for error messages.

Comment: Awesome! Got it figured out. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways to solve this problem. The recommended way assumes you have access to/control over the backend server to this page, where you could load some variable into the model when a certain URL parameter is passed (i.e. `?selection=2`) and when that variable is preset in the model, you can set the `default` parameter on the `select` element.

However, in the event where you only have control over the front end, you can check the URL params or the hash using `document.location` and subsequently make a decision from there.

For example, make the link on the external page be something like `http://www.myurl.com/mypage#option2`. Then in your `<script>` tag, you can check `document.location.hash` for the value `option2` and then call the appropriate jQuery function to change the `select` element.

Comment: `http://www.myurl.com/mypage#option2` will navigate to the element with an `id` of `option2`, it won't select the second `option` of a `select.`